# Shouldn't we use jQuery Migrate in production environment?

Tags: jquery, production-environment, production, jquery-migrate

I found the website below saying that jQuery Migrate should not be used in production environment.
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-migrate-plugin-in-production

I looked for the information for if it is true and why, but I could not find.
Could you please tell me the reasons? jQuery Migrate should be used only for fixing the deprecated features and behaviors?

I actually set the CDNs of newer jQuery and jQuery Migrate without fixing the deprecated methods and the code worked. So I thought there were no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The migrate plugin is to *help you migrate* from one version to another.  It's not to migrate for you.

The idea is that you update your jquery, add the migrate and **it tells you want you need to change.**.  So that you can...well... **actually migrate** to the new jquery.

Also note that migrate only goes from one version to another, running two migrates is not supported as stated [on jquery.com](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#jquery-migrate-plugin).

So if you go from (for example) 1.3->2.0 then need to migrate from 2.0->3.0 (old versions used for examples) it will likely not work as expected.

Finally, migrate works by dumping the information to the `console.log` - and that will also appear on the end-users' browser, which really won't look very good.  (there's no doubt hacks around this, but that's missing the point).

Comment: I pretty appreciate for your reply. I will use jQuery Migrate just to fix deprecated methods. Yes, I actually saw `JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2` shown on Chrome's console, which is not good.